# How to correctly use Mule remote client address property

Tags: http, ip, mule

Intending to keep track of who is sending request to my Rest service in Mule (3.3.0), I did following:

```
<flow name="restService">
        <http:inbound-endpoint  name="endpoint" address="${service.address}"/>
        <logger message="In restService flow, request received from #[header:INBOUND:MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS]" level="INFO" />
        .
        .
        .

    </flow>
```

When I sent a request to this service running on server, I see this in logs:

`In restService flow, request received from /172.23.2.249:54615`

and when external vendor sent request, I see this:

`In restService flow, request received from /172.23.2.249:54604`

Why are the IPs same just with the different of port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the remote port you are seeing, ie the port opened on the remote host to receive responses to requests it's sending to Mule.

Read [What's in an HTTP request?](http://djce.org.uk/dumprequest) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way to know originating client's IP address instead of the middle proxy

Comment: It depends on your "middle proxy": some can be configured to store the remote IP in a specific header, like `X-Forwarded-For` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For). Maybe yours does? Did you check if there is such a header?

Comment: I can see this property coming: `Reverse-Via=ISASRV03` but IP Address is not stored :(

Comment: sure and congratulations on 10k feet :P