# How to retrieve Mule X-MULE headers

Tags: mule

How do i retrieve the values of MULE Headers like X-MULE_ROOT_MESSAGE_ID and X-MULE_SESSION. When I try to use them from #[message.inboundProperties[X-MULE_ROOT_MESSAGE_ID] I am not able to get values. How do I also get the client IP address from Mule HTTP inbound end point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These X- headers are extracted and set directly as message properties or a session object.

So you'll find the content of `X-MULE_ROOT_MESSAGE_ID` by calling `getMessageRootId()` on the `MuleMessage` and you'll get the values serialized in `X-MULE_SESSION` directly in the current `MuleSession` object.

Read this [How to correctly use Mule remote client address property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16921110/387927) to learn more about the remote IP address.

Answer (score 0):

```
#[header:INBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_ID]
```

you can get like this.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to retrive in the java, you can get all the inbound as map (inbound properties) from message context.

Comment: And how can you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use Mule expressions to get the mule session id